# How can I insert multiple queries using loop into database tables using c#?

Tags: c#

How can I put these queries in a **loop** (from **student_fee_record_2** to **student_fee_record_10**) There is only **difference between student_fee_record_1 and others**, from **student_fee_record_2 to 10 have no insertion for fee_txt**. I need them to insert in a loop **separately** from **student_fee_record_1**, So that my code can be shorter, these are too much lines of code, Please help me to short this code using loop. And please note that I’m using **varchar()** for all fields in my database. 
Here is my code.

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "Data Source=Niazi;Initial Catalog=IIHS;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            conDataBase.Open();
            string Query = "insert into student_fee_record_1 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date, fee_submit)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "','" + std_name_txt.Text + "','" + f_name_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "', '" + fee_txt.Text + "');"+

                "insert into student_fee_record_2 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)"+
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_3 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_4 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_5 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_6 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_7 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_8 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_9 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')" +
                "insert into student_fee_record_10 (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                "values('" + std_id_txt.Text + "', '" + std_name_txt.Text + "', '" + f_name_txt.Text + "', " +
                "'" + program_txt.Text + "', '" + address_txt.Text + "', '" + email_txt.Text + "'," +
                "'" + date_txt.Text + "')";

                //SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
                SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                SqlDataReader myReader;
                try
                {
                    //conDataBase.Open();
                    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record added successfully.");
                    ClearAll(this);
                    load_table();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
        }
```

Comment: You've got some of the basics of databases wrong here. You should not have one table per student record - you should have one table only, `student_fee_records`, with an `id` column taking the place of the number on the end of the table name. Also: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should look up how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: We *could* tell you how to achieve what you ask but this would mean sending you off with a solution wrong on so many levels. Reconsider your database design and look into using SqlParameter.

Comment: Holy [sql injection Batman!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: If you want to shorten your code, you can always turn those queries into stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "Data Source=Niazi;Initial Catalog=IIHS;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
            conDataBase.Open();

            string Query = "";

            for (int recordNum = 1; recordNum <= 10; recordNum++)
            {
                if (recordNum == 1)
                {
                    Query = string.Format(
                        "insert into student_fee_record_{0} (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                        "program, address, email_address, date, fee_submit)" +
                        "values('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')",
                        recordNum.ToString(), std_id_txt.Text, std_name_txt, f_name_txt.Text, program_txt.Text, address_txt.Text, date_txt.Text, email_txt.Text, fee_txt.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    Query = string.Format(
                        "insert into student_fee_record_{0} (student_id, student_name, student_f_name," +
                        "program, address, email_address, date)" +
                        "values('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')",
                        recordNum.ToString(), std_id_txt.Text, std_name_txt, f_name_txt.Text, program_txt.Text, address_txt.Text, date_txt.Text, email_txt.Text);
                }

                //SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
                SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
                SqlDataReader myReader;
                try
                {
                    //conDataBase.Open();
                    myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record added successfully.");
                    ClearAll(this);
                    load_table();
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you use my update.  I forgot a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Won't compile. `Query` is accessed outside its scope. And if it did compile, it would be executing all the `MessageBox`, `load_table()` stuff inside the loop. Also, still full of SQL injection.

Comment: I saw the error earlier but was having issues with my network connection and couldn't update.  "string Query" was defined twice.  I fixed.  Will check for more errors.